# Error while creating PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create the procedure below with PL/SQL, but it shows a red cross on the procedure name but no error was displayed so can anyone tell me what's wrong with that code

```
create or replace procedure CREATE_DM_CLIENT(
  V_C_ID   VARCHAR2,
  V_S_ID   VARCHAR2,
  V_A_ID   VARCHAR2,
  V_J      IN  VARCHAR2,
  V_H      IN  VARCHAR2,
  V_COM    IN  VARCHAR2,
  V_COD    OUT VARCHAR2)
is
  code_erreur number;
  lib_erreur  varchar(200) ;
  num         number := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT SEQ_DEM.NEXTVAL  
    INTO NUM  
    FROM  DUAL;
  INSERT  INTO DM_CLIENTS(DM_C_ID, C_ID, S_ID, A, J, H, D_S, C)
     VALUES(num, V_C_ID, V_S_ID, V_A_ID, V_J, V_H, SYSDATE, V_C);
  --update  num_client   set etat=1  where num=V_CLIENT_ID;
  commit;
  V_COD:='100';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
         l_e := SQLERRM ;
         C_L := SQLCODE ;
         insert into l_table (ligne , module) 
           values ( to_char(CODE_ERREUR)||LIB_ERREUR  , 
                    'CREATE_DM_CLIENT' ) ;
         commit;
         V_CODEREP:='109';
end  create_dm_client;
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you run it?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `select nextval` is not necessary. You can use `SEQ_DEM.NEXTVAL` directly in the `values ()` clause.

Comment: "It shows a red cross" - what is "it"? Did you mean [PL/SQL Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info)? If so you need to work in a program window (and tag your question).

Comment: When a stored procedure is compiled, Oracle generates a detailed error list. Please learn how to use your tools properly so that the detailed error list is displayed. If you cannot figure it out using the manuals or the help section, post a new question asking for specific help with your tool.

Comment: You can see what errors are held against invalid objects by running `select * from user_errors;` (or `all_errors` if the object in question doesn't belong to your current schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Compilation errors for PROCEDURE SAC.CREATE_DM_CLIENT

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'L_E' must be declared
Line: 33
Text: l_e := SQLERRM;

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 33
Text: l_e := SQLERRM;

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'C_L' must be declared
Line: 34
Text: C_L := SQLCODE;

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 34
Text: C_L := SQLCODE;

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'V_CODEREP' must be declared
Line: 40
Text: V_CODEREP := '109';

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 40
Text: V_CODEREP := '109';
```

other errors i did not mentioned, was because I don't have table name and sequences.

Comment: seems like you need to declare the variables l_e , C_L  and V_CODEREP

Answer (score 1):

The 3 mentioned variables are not declared.

```
...
is
  v_coderep   varchar2(3);
  c_l         varchar2(3)
  l_e         varchar2(1024);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define l_e, C_L and V_CODEREP variables in variable declaration section. for example -

```
  l_e         varchar(20);
  C_L         integer;
  V_CODEREP   varchar(3);
```